# What is the proper configuration to use PHP Xdebug in VS Code via SSH Remote?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, ssh, xdebug, vscode-remote

I have seen many references to VS Code being able to use Xdebug step debugging over SSH connection, but I've never been able to get it to work. Any explanations-- or tutorials-- I've read always must be missing something, as there are different procedures offered, and none of those I've tried result in a functional step debugging environment.

The following is the Terminal output in VS Code, after establishing a remote SSH Connection. What can I learn from this information that might help me better configure the environment, so using Xdebug Listen will begin the step debugging session when an HTTP request is made?

```
[20:12:44.651] > Running ssh connection command... /home/username/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/e7b5449579249db344d473370d56a5df9446c826/bin/code-server-insiders --start-server --host=127.0.0.1 --accept-server-license-terms --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --port=0 --telemetry-level all   &> "/home/username/.vscode-server-insiders/.e7b5449579249db344d473370d56a5df9446c826.log" < /dev/null
> printenv:
>     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     PWD=/home/username
>     LOGNAME=username
>     XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
>     MOTD_SHOWN=pam
>     HOME=/home/username
>     LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/username/.vscode-server-insiders
>     SSH_CONNECTION=10.xx.xx.02 62663 10.xx.xx.01 22
>     XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
>     USER=username
>     SHLVL=0
>     XDG_SESSION_ID=1826
>     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
>     SSH_CLIENT=10.xx.xx.02 62663 22
[20:12:44.698] > Waiting for server log...
> *
> * Visual Studio Code Server
> *
[20:12:44.744] Received install output: 
[20:12:44.745] Remote server is listening on 41579
[20:12:44.746] Parsed server configuration: {"serverConfiguration":{"remoteListeningOn":{"port":41579},"osReleaseId":"debian","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","sshAuthSock":"","display":"","tmpDir":"/run/user/1000","platform":"linux","connectionToken":"11aa1a11-a11a-1aaa-11a1-11a111a11111"},"serverStartTime":80,"installUnpackCode":""}
[20:12:44.755] > 
[20:12:44.760] Starting forwarding server. localPort 62668 -> socksPort 62646 -> remotePort 41579
[20:12:44.763] Forwarding server listening on 62668
[20:12:44.764] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[20:12:44.768] [Forwarding server 62668] Got connection 0
[20:12:44.774] Tunneled 41579 to local port 62668
[20:12:44.774] Resolved "ssh-remote+10.xx.xx.01" to "127.0.0.1:62668"
[20:12:44.822] ------
[20:12:44.874] [Forwarding server 62668] Got connection 1
[20:12:44.966] [Forwarding server 62668] Got connection 2
```

How do i know if i need to use "tunneling"? AM I using tunneling in this config? What about PuTTY? Would that help the situation?

If more info is needed about my system, please advise.
Thank you!